# Execute mutating function on an object in an array after type cast swift

Tags: swift, types, casting

I have a array which has the type `[myprotocol]`. I also have some types which are conform to `myprotocol`, for example `myType`.

`myType` has a mutating method, which is called `mutateState`.

```
struct myType: myprotocol {
    var state = 0
    mutating func mutateState(){
        state += 1
    }
}
```

I know that my array from earlier has a object with the type `myType` on place 4. And my goal is to call the `mutateState` method on this object. I have to cast the object from the array to have the type `myType`, or else the compiler wouldn't know i can call `mutateState` on it.

My approach was this:

```
(myArrayFromEarlier[3] as! myType).mutateState()
```

But this isn't working because

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type 'myType'

Do you got ideas how to solve this?

Comment: How is `myArrayFromEarlier` declared? If it is a `let`, then it and any `struct`/`enum` values contained inside of it are immutable, and cannot be changed. (You will not be able to call a `mutating` func on those values.)

Comment: Make `mutating func mutateState()` a required method of your protocol, and then you'll be able to call it like this: `myArrayFromEarlier[3].mutateState()`.

Comment: @ItaiFerber `myArrayFromEarlier ` is declared as a var. The reason why I cant mutate the items is my type cast before calling the mutating method

Comment: @vacawama That would have been my fallback solution, but I have like 7 methods which I had to require, and the other types which conform to `myprotocol` don't use them

Comment: Make `myType` a `class`.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quit get how that would help me

Comment: This is a limitation of struct.  If your types are classes, you could call them as you have indicated.

Comment: When `myType` is a `struct`, the cast here using `as!` actually creates an immutable copy of the element and not a reference to it. Changing `myType` to a `class` enables reference semantics, which should allow you to reference the element in the array and directly mutate its properties.

Comment: @Boothosh81 If `myArrayFromEarlier` is mutable, you don't need to change `myType` to a `class`. Have you tried assigning `myArrayFromEarlier[3]` to a local var, mutating that, then assigning back to the array? (i.e., is there a reason this needs to be a one-liner?)

Comment: @ItaiFerber thats actually a good idea. I thought it would be better for the performance if you do it like my first approach. Because otherwise you have to duplicate the item into a local var, and than replace the old item in the array with the new one. But i guess i'll do it like that.

Answer (score 2):

(Note: in this answer I've changed `myprotocol` to `MyProtocol` and `myType` to `MyType` to follow standard Swift naming conventions.)

---

The "Swifty" way to do this would be to add the `mutateState()` method to your protocol and then add a default implementation that does nothing so that you don't have to implement it in your other types that aren't `MyType`:

```swift
protocol MyProtocol {
    mutating func mutateState()
}

extension MyProtocol {
    mutating func mutateState() {}
}
```

And then just call it like so:

```swift
myArrayFromEarlier[3].mutateState()
```

If, however, for some reason you don't want to (or can't) do that, then you'll need to get the element from the array as a mutable `MyType` variable, call `mutateState()` on it, then reinsert it into the array, as in:

```swift
if var element = myArrayFromEarlier[3] as? MyType {
    element.mutateState()
    myArrayFromEarlier[3] = element
}
```

However, it might be kind of a pain to have to do that every time you want to mutate an element of a collection as a different type than the collection's `Element` type. You could add an extension to `MutableCollection` that lets you do the same thing as above but all in one statement, like so:

```swift
extension MutableCollection {
    mutating func mutateElement<T>(at index: Index,
                                   as type: T.Type = T.self,
                                   _ transform: (inout T) throws -> Void) rethrows {
        if var element = self[index] as? T {
            try transform(&element)
            self[index] = element as! Element // This force-cast is safe, as we know `element` must be an `Element` since it originally was in the collection.
        }
    }
}
```

You could then use the above function like this:

```swift
myArrayFromEarlier.mutateElement(at: 3, as: MyType.self) { $0.mutateState() }
```

Comment: The second last idea is great! But how is `MutableCollection` declared?

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not sure what you mean by "But how is `MutableCollection` declared?". `MutableCollection` is a protocol that `Array` conforms to.